# Warum wechselt dieser Schriftsteller vom Konjunktiv I zum Konjunktiv II?

Tags: meaning, subjunctive

Ich lese derzeit *Lieblose Legenden*, eine Sammlung lustiger Kurzgeschichten von Wolfgang Hildesheimer. Folgendes ist ein Exzerpt aus der Geschichte "1956 - ein Pilzjahr".

> 1810 ist Pilz in Berlin, wo er durch einen Zufall Friedrich Ludwig
> Jahn begegnet. Der Patriot ... weiht [Pilz] in seine Pläne ein: er beabsichtigt,
> den Freiheitskampf der alten Germanen gegen die römische
> Gewaltherrschaft in einem groß angelegten Dramenzyklus gleichnishaft
> darzustellen. Einige Vorbereitung und Wappnung zur Hermannsschlacht
> schildernde Szenen hat er schon zu Papier gebracht und will sie
> vorlesen. Pilz wehrt nicht nur energisch ab, sondern beginnt, bei
> dieser Gelegenheit, dem Älteren ins Gewissen zu reden: Jahn **sei** auf
> der falschen Bahn. Hermannsschlachten **gäbe** es schon und **würde** es auch
> in Zukunft zur Genüge geben. (- Prophetische Worte! -)

Wir haben am Ende drei Verben: sei (in Konjunktiv I), dann gäbe und würde (Konjunktiv II). Ich glaube, dass ich verstehe, warum der Schriftsteller "sei" verwendet - das ist einfach indirekte Rede. Wenn ich bisher recht habe (korrigiert mich bitte, wenn nicht), warum wechselt er dann zum Konjunktiv II? Hätte er nicht schreiben können:

> Hermannsschlachten gebe es schon und werde es auch in Zukunft
> zur Genüge geben.

? Hätte das eine andere Bedeutung?

Falls es hilfreich ist, macht der Auszug weiter:

> Nein, so argumentiert Pilz, ohne das Maß seiner geistigen Gaben in
> irgendeiner Weise schmälern zu wollen, lägen vielleicht seine
> wirklichen Fähigkeiten doch auf einem anderen Gebiet - ja, habe er
> denn nicht überhaupt einen geheimen Hang zu Leibesübungen? Wie wäre es
> denn - so Pilz - wenn er diesen Hang zu erhabener Berufung mache und
> sein Leben der Aufgabe weihe, die deutsche Jugend durch körperliche
> Zucht zu kräftigen, indem er ihr diese durch Vorexerzieren vermittle?
> Vielleicht gar solle er sich »Turnvater Jahn« nennen, welcher Name ihm
> sofort einen gewissen bleibenden Nimbus verleihen werde!

Comment: Ich weiẞ nicht, ob du Muttersprachler bist und hoffe, dass dir hier jemand eine profunde Antwort gibt. Ansonsten kann ich nur sagen: Den Unterschied zwischen Konj. 1 und 2 versteht kaum ein deutscher Muttersprachler, der sich nicht irgenfwie intensiv damit auseinandergesetzt hat (im Studium oder so).

Comment: @Olafant: Danke, ja, ich bin Muttersprachler.  Von Englisch.  Ich warte noch auf diese profunde Antwort.

Comment: Wir wünschen uns natürlich alle profunde Antworten - aber: Wenn Sie einen deutschen Text lesen, werden Sie regelmäßig auf Konjunktive stoßen, die nicht den Regeln der Schulgrammatik folgen. Die Verwendung von *gäbe* an Stellen, an denen man *gebe* erwarten würde, ist zum Beispiel ausgesprochen häufig. Sie kann eine Funktion haben (irrealer Nebensinn), oft hat sie aber schlicht keine und das Ganze ist beim Schreiben/Redigieren schlicht nicht aufgefallen. Wäre ich Lektor dieses Textes, würde ich wohl einfach *gäbe* durch *gebe* ersetzen, ohne darin einen Bedeutungsunterschied zu sehen.

Comment: M.E. muss es "werde es" heißen, außer der Satz wäre fortgesetzt mit "(würde es auch in Zukunft geben), wenn der Name Hermann nicht ausstirbt."  (beispielsweise). Beim "gebe/gäbe" bin ich nicht so sicher, und die Sprachtheorie u. Fachtermini beherrsche ich überhaupt nicht - daher kein Antwortversuch von mir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wann kann in indirekter Rede der Konjunktiv I durch den Konjunktiv II ersetzt werden:

1. Wenn der Konjunktiv I die gleiche Form wie der Indikativ Präsens hätte (der Konjunktiv also nicht erkennbar wäre) - Hier nicht der Fall
2. Manche Grammatiken schreiben - "Wenn der Wiedergebende die Aussage des ursprünglichen Sprechers anzweifelt". Das findet man aber nicht überall und es gibt berechtigte Zweifel daran (sic). "Der Angeklagte behauptet, er hätte das Geld nicht aus der Kasse genommen" (das wird auf dem Gerichtsflur vielleicht erzählt. Im Gerichtsprotokoll steht allerdings eher "...er habe das Geld nicht aus der Kasse genommen").  In unserem Beispiel müssten wir dann davon ausgehen, dass der Verfasser meint, dass noch dringend mehr "Herrmannsschlachten gebraucht werden".
3. Im Dialekt oder in regionaler Sprache - Viele Dialekte kennen überhaupt keinen Konjunktiv I
4. Der Originalsprecher (Pilz) sagte nicht etwa "Herrmannsschlachten gibt es schon zur Genüge" sondern stattdessen "Herrmannsschlachten gäbe es schon zur Genüge" (...wenn man sie denn bräuchte) - Er kann also durchaus in der Originalrede schon Konjunktiv II verwendet haben. Dann wäre die Wahl des Konjunktiv II in der Wiedergabe als indirekte Rede durchaus richtig.
5. Zuallerletzt könnte es natürlich auch ganz einfach falsch sein - Die Verwendung des Konjunktivs ist nicht immer ganz einfach. Bei einem Schriftsteller allerdings ziemlich unwahrscheinlich, aber nicht ausgeschlossen.

Ich tendiere zu (4) (in dubio pro reo) und nicht zu (5)

Comment: Danke tofro , sehr interessant.  Passt aber Theorie #4 den eigentlichen Satz? Sie haben das Wort "schon" weggelassen, das mir anscheinend auf die Vergangenheit deutet, wenn man die folgenden Wörter vergleicht, die deutlich auf die Zukunft deuten. Würde es Sinn ergeben, wenn man z. B. sagen würde: "Wenn man solche Theaterstücke bräuchte, gäbe es sie schon und würde es sie auch in Zukunft zur Genüge geben." ? Ich habe jetzt meine Frage bearbeitet, um zusätzlichen Kontext zu geben.

Comment: Genau das ist gemeint - ich habe das "schon" wieder eingefügt, sorry, wenn ich dich verwirrt habe - aber es ändert an sich nichts an der Aussage.

Answer (score 0):

Hier sind einige Punkte erwähnenswert: Im Beispielsatz wird über die Zukunft gesprochen und es liegt indirekte Rede vor.

Futur wird häufig durch Präsens ersetzt, wenn der Kontext bereits klarstellt, dass ein künftiger Vorgang gemeint ist. Hier ist das nicht zu empfehlen, weil der ganze Satz den Kontrast zwischen Jetzt und Zukunft betont, also ist Futur praktisch Pflicht.

Die Pons-Grammatik sagt dazu:

> Der Konjunktiv I Futur I wird aber meistens nur noch in der der 3. Person Singular benutzt. [...] Für alle anderen Personen verwendet man stattdessen die Umschreibung mit *würde* + Infinitiv.

Hier liegt 3. Person im Plural vor. Dass das mit Konjunktiv II übereinstimmt, ist eher Zufall als ein Bedeutungsunterschied.

Comment: Danke @guidot, aber ich verstehe es nicht.  Hier liegt doch die dritten Person Singular (nicht Plural) vor, oder? "gäbe es" und "würde es" wie ursprünglich geschrieben, oder "gebe es" und "werde es" in meiner Version. Wir haben natürlich auch die Frage von "gäbe" gegen "gebe," die das Futur nicht betrifft.

Comment: @cruthers: I was misled by the plural *Herrmannsschlachten* (which is an unusual plural, since there is exactly one historically), but you are right, that the omitted *es* is the correct object and would be singular too.

Comment: The plural *Hermannsschlachten* could refer to literature. Various authors have written about that event, for example von Kleist and Klopstock.

Comment: @PaulFrost - I think that's right.  The story is a tribute to the (fake) underappreciated historical figure Pilz:  "Seine Bedeutung wird heute weit unterschätzt. Das ist nicht verwunderlich. Denn er war weniger ein Schöpfer als ein Dämpfer. Sein Beitrag zur Geschichte der abendländischen Kultur kommt in der Nichtexistenz von Werken zum Ausdruck, Werken die durch sein mutiges, obferbereites Dazwischentreten niemals entstanden sind."

Comment: ich bestreite, das "Hermannsschlachten gebe es zur Genüge" singular sei. Das Indefinitpronomen kann, wie Guidot schon ganz richtig sagt, auch als Objekt stehen (vgl. bspw. Schlachten seien *hier/es* schon zur Genüge), ohne Bedeutung für den grammatischen Nummerus der Verbalphrase zu haben. Zwar ist diese Lesart sicher unüblich, so dass mir nicht klar ist, was Guidot eigentlich damit meint. Die Wiederholung lässt es ja doch als *identity of reference anaphor" erscheinen, zumindeyt im zweiten Glied.

Comment: @vectory Tut mir leid, das ist Unsinn. Natürlich hat der Originalsprecher "Herrmansschlachten gibt/gäbe es zur Genüge" und nicht "Herrmannschlachten geben es zur Genüge" gesagt. Daher ist das sehr offensichtlich Singular.

Comment: @tofro achso, na dann. Vergleich bitte mal *Es fehlen dir die Argumente*. Das ist meines erachtens üblich. Richtig wäre sprachhistorisch betrachtet eher *gäbet* oder so ähnlich. Nachdem das aus der Mode gefallen ist, wurde die Endung offensichich dem indefinitpronomen angepasst. Siehe auch *es regnet*. (Das zieh ich mir grad auf drei Gramm Fentanyl aus dem allerwertesten und hoffe auf zuträgliche Regierung, also nix fürungut)

Answer (score -1):

Ein weiterer Vorschlag zur Erklärung des Satzes:

> ... Jahn sei auf der falschen Bahn. Hermannsschlachten gäbe es schon
> und würde es auch in Zukunft zur Genüge geben.

"sei" ist klar: oratio obliqua

"gäbe" steht aber nicht einfach parallel zu "sei". Hier liegt ja eine Gegenüberstellung von Vergangenheit und Zukunft vor: es hat schon Hermannschlachten gegeben und es wird noch mehr davon geben. Wandelt man das Präteritum "gab" und das Hilfsverb "wird" in Konjunktiv um, so ergeben sich die Konjunktiv-II-Formen. Wie die entsprechende Regel dazu lautet, habe ich keine Ahnung, der syntaktische Sachverhalt scheint jedoch einleuchtend.

Comment: Ich kann der Argumentation nicht folgen. Spätestens bei "Wandelt man das Präteritum 'gab' und das Hilfsverb 'wird' in Konjunktiv um, so ergeben sich die Konj.-II-Formen" haben Sie mich verloren. Wenn Sie indikativ. Verbformen in Konj. II umwandeln, kommen naturgemäß Konj.-II-Formen heraus. Erklärungsbedürftig wäre gerade, warum *sein* im Konj. I und das nachfolgende *geben* im Konj. II steht. Dafür habe ich noch keine Erklärung gehört (m.E. gibt es schlicht keine). Wollte man mit *geben* Vorzeitigkeit ausdrücken, gäbe es dafür im Übrigen auch eine Konj.-I-Möglichkeit: *habe es schon gegeben*.

Answer (score -1):

Ein ganz wichtiger Punkt, der hierbei zu berücksichtigen wehre: die Vokale werden landläufig allesamt gleichgesprochen, egal ob *gebe / gäbe*, *wer / wäre / wehre / währe*, zumal der Konjunktiv II in Umgangspsprache zumeist durch würdevolle Konstruktionen ersetzt wird. Eine gewollte Unterscheidung kann zwar betont werden, kann abseits dessen für den Sprecher (inkl. Muttersprachler) jedoch schwierig zu erlernen sein und dahingehend auch zu Hyperkorrektur führen.

Ganz ähnlich verhielt es sich meines Erachtens mit *wird* und *würd'*. Es ist in der Mundart gehupft wie gesprung' wie man so sagt. Zwar ist *werde* davon zu unterscheiden. Die Ironie an der Sache:

analog zu *geben, es gibt, gab, gebe, gäbe* müsste ja *werden, es wird, war(d), wäre, ...* ebenso in *wärd enden, doch folgt *würde* aus *wurde* statt *ward*. Momentemal, was ist *ward*? Wolfgang Pfeifer nennt es schon nicht mehr, selbst Jacob Grimm führt es nicht auf, doch finden sich im DWB durchaus Zitate; dazu empfiehlt sich eine Lesung unter dem Stichwort [sein](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/sein), insb. Abschnitt I. Nummer 33) Ziffer b. bzgl. des Passiv. Das ist so vielschichtig und undurchsichtig, dass ich das lieber viel später ausführen möchte. Im kurzen Schluss (TL;DR) sollte eine Ableitung von der Vergangenheitsform in den Konjunktiv zwangsläufig irrealis Stimmung bedeuten (*werde*) und dementgegen die Ableitung zu *würde* viel eher aus der Vergangenheit heraus auf die Zukunft bis dato gerichtet ebenfalls irrealis sein. Eine weitere Unterscheidung in Potentialis im Vegangenen (falls ungewiss ist, ob weitere Herrmansschlachten bereits statt fanden) bzw. auf die ferne Zukunft abzgl. gewisser Vegangenheit wird in unserer Sprache aber genau nicht beobachtet, so dass mein vorangegangener Satz wohl hinfällig ist.

Dementsprechend handelt es sich meinem Sprachgefühl nach viel eher um eine dramaturgische Steigerung. Ob man das als Irrealis oder indirekter Rede potentiell liest, ist gleich, denn der Passiv mit *geben* drückt bereits aus, dass die Ereignisse auserhalb der Einflussnahme der Sprecher liegent seien.